# Make table with attributes in Symfony 5

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony5

I run this command on my terminal in vscode `php bin/console make:entity article` but it shows me a red message as abort.

I don't understand why it does not let me type the properties.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi  The problem was caused by PHP 7.4.0, you'll need the latest PHP 7.4 development build that has the fix (they call it snapshots)

https://windows.php.net/snapshots/

You can test with PHP7.4.0, Revision: r505cc77 (December 09 2019, 20:51:21), ***VC15 x64 Non Thread Safe***